# Eclipse Plugin project - change build directory by code

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am creating an Eclipse plugin that creates a C project which will be compiled with a makefile.
I want to change the build dirctory of the C/C++ project. I don't want to change it manually (right click -> properties -> C/C++ build -> Builder Settings -> Build directiry), but to change it using Java code in my Plugin project.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way:

```
configuration.getEditableBuilder().setBuildPath("path/to/build/directory");
```